# Selenium Chromedriver fails to open URL when triggered from Jenkins

Tags: java, google-chrome, jenkins, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have a Windows 10 desktop which is configured as a Jenkins slave (starts via JNLP webstart).

When I trigger the job to run UI tests on this slave it fails to open the application URL (shows the default `data;` in address bar). I am using Chrome v63 (tried with Chromedriver 2.34 and 2.35; both compatible). But strangely when I trigger the same Maven command to run the tests from command line or eclipse on this box it works fine. Reinstalled Chrome but same problem.

Please help.

Comment: Does it throw any exception?

Comment: Nope, it does not.

Comment: You're trying to execute maven command from Jenkins as well, right? Or how do you run your tests from Jenkins?

Comment: I trigger maven command from Jenkins as well

Comment: @saikosen And chromedriver is loaded how? Relative project path?